# How can I solve a non continuous equation in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function:

```
p = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
EU = (((-(1.3+1-0.5)**(1.2-1.5)/(1-1.5)))**-1)*p + (((-(0.1+1-0.5)**(1.2-1.5)/(1-1.5)))**-1)*(1-p)
```

And I would like to solve this to get a value of p where EU == 0.5.
My issue is that I checked manually and the p value is 0.4244, but in the function p jumps with steps of 0.01.

Now I'm fine with getting the closest p value where EU is closest to 0.5, but I'm worried the code will not find an answer, since none of the values from the p array will return exactly 0.5 for EU. How could I solve this?

Comment: The formula is just linear in `p`; none of the "scary" terms involve it, they are just constants. You can analytically solve this for `p`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Technically yes, but I'm required to solve it with a function

Comment: Well, what exactly are the requirements, then? So far the technical description is rather vague – for example, this starts with "I have a function" then does not show a function.

Comment: EU is the function @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function is a simple linear function, so it could be simply found by just a simple binary search, however if the funciton was more complex and you needed to really calculate the gradient and runt he optimization you could use torch or jax or any other autograd tools to do that

```
import torch
def func(p):
    return (((-(1.3+1-0.5)**(1.2-1.5)/(1-1.5)))**-1)*p + (((-(0.1+1-0.5)**(1.2-1.5)/(1-1.5)))**-1)*(1-p)


x = torch.tensor([0.1], requires_grad=True)
loss = 1
# 1e-7 example threshold for answer to stop
while loss > 1e-7:
    x.retain_grad()
    y = func(x)
    loss = (y - torch.tensor([0.5], requires_grad=True)) ** 2 
    # or use MSELoss from nn  
    loss.backward()
    x = x - 0.1 * x.grad # naive gradient decent with lr = 0.1

print(x.item())

0.42235034704208374
```

Comment: you are very welcome, just consider that this is considering that the original function could be complex, otherwise if really you want to just find for the EU function in the example it is overkill.

Comment: It is a bit more complex, I just simplified it for the example, but in hindsight that was a mistake haha